# Jquery hover and hover out ellipsis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a long title and I make it ellipsis mean `...` when not hover, then when I hover the long title will show full length, from here I already make it using jquery with css `ellipsis`, so far I have a problem is when I mouseout how to return the long title to `ellipsis` again ? Thanks

[Click here for the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qnhcudp/3/)

Comment: WHAT does not work? Tons of code to look at....

Comment: simplify your question or your will get lots of down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that the Title of the pop-up vanishes once its hovered on then just call the render function first & then call popup function.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qnhcudp/4/

Code:

```
<script>
    var array = [];
$(function() {
    array[0] = {
        "no": "1",
            "name": "fruit",
            "value": "mango",
            "totalvote": "75"
    };
    array[1] = {
        "no": "2",
            "name": "fruit",
            "value": "apple",
            "totalvote": "10"
    };
    array[2] = {
        "no": "3",
            "name": "fruit",
            "value": "orange",
            "totalvote": "5"
    };
    array[3] = {
        "no": "4",
            "name": "fruit",
            "value": "banana",
            "totalvote": "45"
    };

    PG.init("popup_survey_whitebox_selection", "1", array);
    PG.render_1();    
    PG.callpopup();


});
</script>
```

Comment: @ImHappy I called the render_1() prior to callpopup().

Comment: LOL haha just like that only !